Issue with Gitlab CE setup with HA in AWS
Trying to setup Gitlab CE with HA (for 3000 users) in AWS. i am following documentation from gitlab.com but here i am trying to setup with AWS services like Elasticache(Redis) , RDS and EC2. i am facing issue with adding preafect instances to LoadBalancer.
I see process is running and port is also Listening.
root@ip-15-0-5-232:/home/ubuntu# sudo gitlab-ctl status praefect
run: praefect: (pid 14400) 12241s; run: log: (pid 2484) 16987s
root@ip-15-0-5-232:/home/ubuntu#

root@ip-15-0-5-232:/home/ubuntu# netstat -anp | grep -i 2305
tcp6       0      0 :::2305                 :::*                    LISTEN      14405/praefect
root@ip-15-0-5-232:/home/ubuntu#


Tried accessing using localhost but getting error as below.
root@ip-15-0-5-152:/etc/gitlab# curl --http1.1 http://localhost:2305/-/readiness
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

But while trying to add it to Load Balancer (NLB) i still see the health check is failing given below are the ELB config.
NLB config

Target-group setting


need suggestion on how to troubleshoot it.
